# Notepad++ Explorer Plugin Context Menu not showing TortoiseSVN

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, notepad++, context-menu, tortoise-svn

I installed Notepad++ 6.0 and the Explorer Plugin. When I right click a file in the side window, I don't get options for TortoiseSVN.

When right clicking on a file in Windows Explorer, I do see options for TortoiseSVN.

Any ideas on why this might be?

Comment: Do any other non-Microsoft context/shell menus work inside the Notepad++ Explorer plugin?

Comment: The ones that "ought" to appear include 7-zip, TortoiseSVN, and avast's "scan this file". The only one that does appear inside Notepad++ Explorer is "scan this file" from avast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notepad++ is 32bit. Perhaps you have only TortoiseSVN 64bit Client installed. I had the same issue with Total Commander at work. Try installing TortoiseSVN 32bit Client also.

Comment: From [TortoiseSVN.net](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-quick-start.html) 

> TortoiseSVN runs on Windows XP with service pack 3
> or higher and is available in both 32-bit and 64-bit
> flavours. The installer for 64-bit Windows also includes
> the 32-bit extension parts. Which means you don't need
> to install the 32-bit version separately to get the
> TortoiseSVN context menu and overlays in 32-bit applications.

Comment: This is true for new versions of TortoiseSVN. Quote from TortoiseSVN FAQ: 'After installing, TortoiseSVN does not show up, no context menus are available
Make sure you have installed the x64 version of TortoiseSVN if you're using XP or Vista 64-bit. Since the explorer on those OS versions is a 64-bit application, it can not load the 32-bit version of TortoiseSVN.

You can still keep the 32-bit version of TortoiseSVN installed on those OS versions though: it will show up in the 32-bit applications file-open/save dialogs of those applications.' You didn't mention the version.

Comment: I will attempt to install 32-bit. I am running TortoiseSVN 1.5.10. My SVN server is still 1.4, so an older client here is a must (for the short-term).  Which config will be obeyed if I install two version?

Comment: Both are using the same .svn directories.

Comment: I installed 32-bit tortoisesvn, restarted windows, and notepad++ with light explorer plugin is working as expected. Thanks.